# Change color of button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm having trouble changing the color of a button with a simple function, the color doesn't change at all.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

     <script language="JavaScript">

        function changeColor(){
             document.getElementsByTagName('button').style.backgroundColor="green";
        }

     </script>

    </head>

    <body >

        <form action="/action_page.php" method="get" name="form1">
            <input type="text" id="campoDeFlores">
            <button type="button" onclick="changeColor()" name="1">1</button>
            <button type="button"  name="2">2</button>
            <button type="button"  name="3">3</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName#Example) returns an `array` which means you have to loop to access each element.

Comment: See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/7q1zk42w/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an list of elements not a single element. You need to convert it to an array with `Array.from` and then iterate over the buttons with `Array.map`

```
function changeColor(){
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')).map(function(button) {
               button.style.backgroundColor="green";
    })
}
```

Comment: Just to complement: you can also do this changing `document.querySelectorAll('button')` to  `document.getElementsByTagName('button')`. Also you could use `.forEach` instead of `.map` as you don't need to return a result.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I think `querySelector` is better because the OP might want to change the condition. Isn't forEach just ES6?

Comment: OK. Just telling the OP that option. About forEach being ES6 only, no it isn't: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach (see Specifications section)

Comment: oh ok :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

#### HTML

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" name="form1">
  <input type="text" id="campoDeFlores">
  <button type="button" onclick="changeColor(this)" name="1">1</button>
  <button type="button" name="2">2</button>
  <button type="button" name="3">3</button>
</form>
```

#### JS

```
function changeColor(btn) {
  btn.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

[Check this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7q1zk42w/).

#### Explanation

At first I thought you were trying to change the color of all the buttons because you were using [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) but it looks like you just want to change the color of the button that was pressed. In that case you don't need to use an array. Just pass the element that was clicked to the function and then change that specific button's color.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using `id="myButton"` and `document.getElementById('myButton')` to specifically select a button instead of *every* `button`.

Comment: This is the real solution

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes:

- allow your `changeColor` function to accept a HTMLElement as
  parameter.
- Pass reference to button to `changeColor()`. Change
  `onclick="changeColor()"` in `button` element to
  `onclick="changeColor(this)"`

```js
function changeColor (htmlEl) {
  htmlEl.style.backgroundColor="green";
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" name="form1">
    <input type="text" id="campoDeFlores">
    <button type="button" onclick="changeColor(this)" name="1">1</button>
    <button type="button"  name="2">2</button>
    <button type="button"  name="3">3</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of button and you want to color and uncolor it by clicking it.you can use if statement inside event listener.This feature is used specific in booking something.

HTML

```
<button class="btnco">1</button>
<button class="btnco">2</button>
```

CSS

```
.btnco{

     background-color: green;
    }
```

JS

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btnco').forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (this.style.backgroundColor=="red"){
            this.style.backgroundColor="green"
        }else{
      this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

*im* *testing* *this`function randomcolour(){ document.getElementsByTagName('button').style.backgroundColor=`${ var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 24));
return '#' + ('00000' + num.toString(16)).substr(-6);}`;

}`*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).